# Why is python somehow overwriting my function with another function in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, which fails:

```
def test_function_combining_wrong():
    def one():
        print("ONE")
        return "ONE"
    
    def two():
        print("TWO")
        return "TWO"
    
    F1S = {
        1: one,
        2: two,
    }
    F2S = {
        **{key: lambda: value() for key, value in F1S.items()},
    }
    print("1st Call")
    assert F1S[1]() == "ONE"
    assert F1S[2]() == "TWO"
    print("2nd Call")
    assert F2S[1]() == "ONE"  # ATTENTION: THIS IS WRONG WEIRD PYTHON STUFF
    assert F2S[2]() == "TWO"
```

In my head this code should work and I would like to know why Python returns `TWO` for the `F2S[1]()`. I'm trying to nest some lambda functions together in dictionaries.

Comment: Because the value of `value` will be looked up when `lambda: value()` gets called, and at that time the last value `value` had was the function `two`.

Comment: That sounds logical. Do you know of a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `lambda: value()`, you get a lambda function that will evaluate `value()` when it's called. But after the `for key, value in F1S.items()` loop is finished, `value` will have the value of the last item in `F1S` so all the lambda functions you created will use this last value which in this case returns `"TWO"`.

One way to fix this is to make an extra binding for `value`, by using `lambda value=value: value()` instead. This will create a `value` variable for each iteration of the loop which will have the correct value for that iteration.

Comment: This answer is correct, but in this case, the easier thing to do would be to replace the whole lambda with just `value`.

Comment: @Jasmijn That's true. I assumed this was a simplified version of the code and the original might do more than just `value()`, so I suggested the more general approach.